# Find set of points where a multivariable function is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have this function $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2-y^2}$ defined in a subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and need to find where it is differentiable. I know it is continuous, and I found the partial derivatives using derivation rules:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}},\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$$
They are also continuous in the interior of $D$, but not in the boundaries, so the function is differentiable at least in $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 > y^2\}$. Now, can I simply say the partial derivatives don't exist at $x^2=y^2$, meaning the function is not differentiable there, or do I need to prove it with the formal definition of a partial derivative (using the limit)?

Comment: That depends on your definition of differentiable when speaking of points which are not in the interior.

Comment: Digitallis is correct. You need to look in your text and find out exactly what definitions it uses for points on the boundary. While I believe it is more common to not define differentiation at boundary points at your level, that is far from a universal choice. So we cannot advise you on what your particular course is doing. You will have to look that up yourself.